# Recursion binary method in java not working

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, recursion, binary-search-tree

[This is the code. Please tell me what I am doing wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXtW2.png)
So this is a Java program to do binary search using a recursive method. It takes an array and a search variable.

I know there is something wrong but I am not sure what it is. 
What am I doing wrong and how to change it?

```
public static int binary(int arr[], int target) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = arr.length;
    int mid = (start+end)/2;

    if(end<start) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (arr[mid] == target) {
        return mid;
    }
    else if (arr[mid] > target) {
        start = mid + 1;
        int[] newArr = new int[end];
        for(int i=start;i<end;i++) {
            int j=0;
            newArr[0] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
        return binary(newArr,target);
    } else {
        end = mid - 1;
        int[] newArr = new int[end];
        for(int i=start;i<end;i++) {
            newArr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        return binary(newArr,target);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post a [mre] in your question, rather than a picture of some code; and describe in detail what problem you are having.

Comment: Kindly put only your question to the title and give details after. Sharing the code here will help people who want to answer your question.

Comment: Please post your code as text not as an image!

Comment: The code has been posted!

Answer (score 1):

I'll point out that by copying parts of the array in a new smaller array, you're undercutting the value of doing a binary search. A well implemented binary search runs in O(log(n)) time, whereas what you're doing here runs in O(n). Instead, if you'd like to implement a binary search recursively, you should just pass the original array and the upper and lower bounds that you're currently considering.

That said, the reason that your code isn't even getting a correct answer, much less getting it quickly, is due to a few different bugs.

- Assuming that your array is pre-sorted in ascending order (a binary search can't work at all if your array isn't sorted order), then you have the case where the midpoint is greater than the target and the case where the midpoint is smaller than the target reversed.
- Your code for copying the high end of the array has a few issues. As a reminder, if you're copying parts of your array, then you're doing a binary search incorrectly. That said, your array copying code for this case only writes to the starting index of the new array `[0]` instead of walking along the new array and old array at the same time.

Comment: If you can rewrite the changes to be made, i might be able to understand better

Comment: Is there any way where you can recursively do it without passing the upper and lower bounds?